# When should I use CSSStylesheet.insertRule

Tags: javascript, html, css

When would it be a good time to use the [CSSStylesheet.insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) over using the [style object in the DOM elements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)?

I guess i'm wondering about the performance differences between the two

Comment: I guess the difference is that the [Style Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) only allows us to manipulate simple, primitive values like colors, etc. whereas [CSSStylesheet.insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) allows us to insert complete and complex CSS rules

Comment: I understand that's the difference but i was wondering if there was any sort of performance difference

Comment: that depends on your use case... but I don't think there is much performance cost associated with either method... don't fall prey to [Over Optimising](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) your code